# I am trying to write code to me sent to multiple emails

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to send a cell change in a google sheet to multiple emails; how to I do that?

I would also like to be able to have a list of multiple cells that if any changes, I get the email. Currently I can only go it for one cell and send it to one email. Also I need to fix the email message so that it pulls the cell numbers sheet name at the change. Right now it just sats `${range} ${sName} @{e.value}` in red and not black like the video I watched.

```
function onEdit(e){
  const ss = e.source;
  const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const sName = sheet.getName();
  const range = 'G4';
  if(e.range.getA1Notation()==range){
    const subject = 'Cell edited';
    const email = 'matt@fremonthabitat.org';
    const message = 'The cell in range ${range} was edited. Sheet name ${sName} \nNew Value is ${e.value}'
    MailApp.sendEmail(email,subject,message)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use this**

```
 function send(e) {
  const sName = e.source.getSheetName();
  const range = e.range.getA1Notation();
  console.log(range);
  const rangesArr = ['G4', 'G6', 'G7'];
  if (rangesArr.some(i => range.includes(i))) {
    const obj = { subject: 'Cell edited', email: 'some email' }
    const message = `The cell in range ${range} was edited. Sheet name ${sName} \nNew Value is ${e.value}`
    MailApp.sendEmail(obj.email, obj.subject, message)
  }
}
```

But don't forget [quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) limit

- If there are a lot of recipients, you can try using this [case](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/44e055214ab470c9b3143a469d7a7d21)
- Only if you edit cells very quickly `onEdit` won't always be able to keep up with you

**it works**

[image]

Comment: This line should have backticks not single quotes `const message = 'The cell in range ${range} was edited. Sheet name ${sName} \nNew Value is ${e.value}'
    `

Comment: You are using the wrong kind of double quotes in this line `const emails = [“email1”, “email2”, …other emails];`